# how to plot lines linking medians of multiple violin distributions in seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I struggle hard to succeed in plotting a dot-line between the median values (and min and max) per type of stacked violin distributions.
I tried superposing a violin plot with a seaborn.lineplot but it failed. I'm not sure with this approach that I can draw dot-lines and also link min and max of distributions of the same type. I also tried to use seaborn.lineplot but here the challenge is to plot min and max of the distribution at each x-axis value.

Here is a example dataset and the code for the violin plot in seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x=[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8]
cate=['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
y=[1.1,1.12,1.13,1.13,3.1,3.12,3.13,3.13,5.1,5.12,5.13,5.13,2.2,2.22,2.25,2.23,4.2,4.22,4.25,4.23,6.2,6.22,6.25,6.23,2.2,2.22,2.24,2.23,4.2,4.22,4.24,4.23,6.2,6.22,6.24,6.23,1.1,1.13,1.14,1.12,3.1,3.13,3.14,3.12,5.1,5.13,5.14,5.12]

my_pal =['red','green', 'purple']

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'Type': cate, 'y': y})
ax=sns.catplot(y='y', x='x',data=df, hue='Type', palette=my_pal,  kind="violin",dodge =False) 
sns.lineplot(y='y', x='x',data=df, hue='Type', palette=my_pal,  ci=100,legend=False)
plt.show()
```

but it plots line only on a reduce part of the left of the plot. Is there a trick to superpose lineplot with violin plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the line plot, 'x' is considered numerical. However, for the violin plot 'x' is considered categorical (positioned at 0, 1, 2, ...).

A solution is to convert 'x' to strings to have both plots consider it as categorical.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_pal = ['red', 'green', 'purple']
N = 40
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(1, 6, N*3) * 0.2,
                   'y': np.random.uniform(0, 1, N*3) + np.tile([2, 4, 6], N),
                   'Type': np.tile(list('abc'), N)})
df['x'] = [f'{x:.1f}' for x in df['x']]
ax = sns.violinplot(y='y', x='x', data=df, hue='Type', palette=my_pal, dodge=False)
ax = sns.lineplot(y='y', x='x', data=df, hue='Type', palette=my_pal, ci=100, legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.margins(0.15)  # slightly more padding for x and y axis
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]